# Arrow_Down does not work properly after the contextClick() in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have below code part, I am just trying to right click on the element and getting the property window, then I am going to select the last option of that window. How to use `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` to achieve that ?

I used the below code, but did not work for me even though the element is captured correctly.

```
 Actions rightClickAction = new Actions(webDriver).contextClick(element_x)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

rightClickAction.build().perform();
```

The property window is like below.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnNpz.jpg)

Comment: Is that property window belongs to windows or browser ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I cannot see the list of elements by inspect element in the browser level,  so that I am assuming it belongs to windows

Comment: If it belongs to windows , then selenium can't help you. But may be your binding language can do.

Comment: cruisepandey , can you bit explain on that ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can help you on that, if your scripts are gonna run on windows machines only then you may try with AutoIT.

Comment: If click on 'Properties' calls any javascript method, you can get the script and run it without even opening the context menu. Can you provide page source code or better url?